# vuejs 3 dynamically setting select in options from an array of objects

Tags: drop-down-menu, vuejs3

I have a select option in a vue 3 component like this:

```js
<div v-for="line in lines" :key="line.id">
    <select v-model="form.categorie">
        <option
            v-for="value in categories"
            :key="value.id"
            :value="value.id"
            :selected=
        >
            {{ value.intitule }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

A `line` contains: `{ "id": 479, "intitule": "blabla", "categorie": "foo" }`

`categories` comes from a pinia store and contains:
`[ { "id": 53, "intitule": "foo" }, { "id": 55, "intitule": "footoo" }, { "id": 56, "intitule": "barbar" }]`

I want to achieve that the categorie of a given `line` shows up as selected in the select dropdown.

Despite this already having been asked here, I can't get this to work.

I have tried:

```
:selected="line.categorie"
```

and:

```
:selected="categories.intitule === line.categorie"
```

or hardcoded:

```
:selected="footoo"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone bumping into this question and expanding on the explanations in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#select), this achieves the purpose:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selected" @change="set_select()" >
    <option 
      v-for="option in options"
      :value="option.id"
    >
      {{ option.intitule }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div>Selected: {{ selected }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref, reactive, onMounted } from 'vue';
const selected = ref(57)
const options = ref([
  { id: 53, intitule: "foo" },
  { id: 55, intitule: "footoo" },
  { id: 56, intitule: "doodoo" },
  { id: 54, intitule: "barbaz" },
  { id: 57, intitule: "barbars" }
])
const form = reactive({
  cat:''
})
onMounted(() => {
  set_select()
})
const set_select = () => {
  form.cat = selected.value
}
</script>
```